# Angularui bootstrap datepicker - how to set icon classes on the datepicker prev/next buttons?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui

I'm using this template: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/bootstrap-elements.html and all the icons have the classes `fa` and `fa-chevron-right` for example instead of `icon` and `icon-chevron-right`.

The Angular-uiui bootstrap datepicker has this icon for the "next" button:

```
<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
```

How can I change it to:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
```

Comment: add in you custom css `icon-chevron-right` class empty and set `fa fa-chevron-right`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use single `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` at the very bottom of it there is section where all the templates are declared. Just look for all places where `icon` is present and change it to `fa` -- or use auto-replacement (it should not change anything else than `css` classes, but use responsibly;-)). That should be enough.

If you use just template for the datepicker: it is even easier, as you have to modify one file.

Comment: hmm, what about maintenance? next time he wants to update `ui-bootstrap` with new version and we can forget to change/override style

Comment: @MaximShoustin That's what I was thinking. Ideally i'd like a solution which doesn't involve hacking on the source, but i'm not sure if that is available with this version.

Comment: @MaximShoustin for sure maintenance is an issue. But for now `ui-bootstrap` is based on out-dated version of `bootstrap` and in the next release it will not be supported any way.

Comment: @Catfish The `css` classes are just hard-coded in the templates and are exactly the same as in `bootstrap`. Do not understand what *kind of hacking* you are talking about. You can use whatever template you want. There is even the official distributed version without any default templates.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Can you provide an example of how I would use my own custom template without having to modify `ui-bootstrap.js`? Also, if this is out-dated, is there something that I should be using?

Comment: @Catfish I am using `ui-boostrap.js` with `bootstrap3` and I think it is **just** great (had to tweak the template in some places). Every directive (with visual content) of `ui-boostrap.js` has an option `templateUrl` if you cannot change the url change the file it points to.

Comment: @Catfish btw. the file `ui-bootstrap.js` points to templates defined by `urls` and `ui-bootstrap.min.js` has templates built-in.

Comment: Can you provide a url to ui-bootstrap.js?

Comment: @Catfish [http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) -- the main page of the project Getting Started->Files to Download. And will cite for you: *Build files for all directives are distributed in several flavours: minified for production usage, un-minified for development, with or **without templates**.*